# AutoMapper does not map Null value on Nullable property, why?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Here is a small code snippet that illustrate the problem.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AutoMapper_MappingNullValue_ShouldMapNull()
{
    //Arrange
    var source = new DummySource { MyDate = null };
    var destination = new DummyDestination { MyDate = DateTime.Now };
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<DummySource, DummyDestination>();

    //Act
    var returnResult = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(source, destination);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNull(returnResult.MyDate);
    Assert.IsNotNull(destination.MyDate);
}

private class DummySource
{
    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
}

private class DummyDestination
{
    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

How come this fail on the first assert? I expected to have a null value on the result. In fact, `returnResult` and `destination` are both with their initial value.

Comment: It's not failing the first assert. The second assert should be failing since you're mapping `source` to `destination` and thus `destination.MyDate` is `null`. Use `var returnResult = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<DummySource, DummyDestination>(source);` to preserve the existing object.

Comment: @Romoku See by yourself http://imgur.com/KG0XJVj

Comment: Which version of AutoMapper are you using? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: 2.2.0.0 is the version

Comment: The behavior is different in v3.0.0. Try updating the nuget package.

Comment: I can confirm that. Works fine in 3.1.1.

Comment: Thank you guys, let me check if I have the authorization to update. I will give you some news if I can update the library to let you know if it worked.

Comment: [#310 fixed the issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/310). There shouldn't be any [breaking changes](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/releases/tag/v3.0.0) from 2.2 -> 3.X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the nuget package.

This was fixed in [issue #310](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/310). The first version to implement the change is [3.0.0](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/releases/tag/v3.0.0).